# How to recover files on NTFS partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-xp, ntfs

Good people’s with askubunty samy to to try ask in superuser so I copy questions.

I have very, very horrible problem.
I have 3 partitions in my computer: Linux, Windows and NTFS Data and I have a problem with the Data partition. It is... empty?! I lost a lot of news materials for study.

**Output of `lsblk`:**

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    20G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  38,2G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   1,9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0 172,9G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

`sda6` is the problematic partition. If I mount it on Ubuntu I see only two files, which I can't open, in the folder `System Volume Information`.

**Output of `ls -A` in the folder:**

```
MountPointManagerRemoteDatabase  tracking.log
```

When I start Windows XP, the system sees the disk as empty. Linux also sees a lot of free space.

For context, I installed new .NET and a game in Windows XP and rebooted it. Windows made a fast check disk (probably `chkdsk`) and I saw that some shortcuts didn't have icons. I clicked the Data partition ans it was empty! I restarted to check with Ubuntu and posted here.

**Testdisk scan:**

```
Disk /dev/sda - 250 GB / 232 GiB - CHS 30401 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
 1 * HPFS - NTFS              0   1  1  2610 254 63   41945652
 2 P Linux                 2611  22 36  7590 202 36   79998976
 3 E extended              7590 235  4 30401  75 10  366448642
 5 L Linux Swap            7590 235  6  7833 230 13    3903488
   X extended              7834   0  1 30401  75 10  362543590
 6 L HPFS - NTFS           7834   7 46 30401  75 10  362543104 [Dane]
```

**Quick search:**

```
Disk /dev/sda - 250 GB / 232 GiB - CHS 30401 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
 1 * HPFS - NTFS              0   1  1  2610 254 63   41945652
 2 P Linux                 2611  22 36  7590 202 36   79998976
 3 E extended              7590 235  4 30401  75 10  366448642
 5 L Linux Swap            7590 235  6  7833 230 13    3903488
   X extended              7834   0  1 30401  75 10  362543590
 **6 L HPFS - NTFS           7834   7 46 30401  75 10  362543104 [**Dane]
```

In my opinion the file system was damaged. Unfortunately, I don't have another disk for recovery operations.

Moreover, the undelete list in Testdisk is empty. Standard check disk in Windows make to same - no errors (i force chdsk in start and use fast checking in windows-level).

Comment: I would try to use a recovery live cd/dvd such as Hirens Boot CD or Ultimate Boot CD and boot using the live version of that, THEN check the drive and see if you can see the files.

Comment: Hiren Boot CD is a huge collection of pirated software, hence avoid it. Having said that, the following solution was already linked in the AU question: http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271